# Getting picture stream error in Flutter Application

Tags: android, flutter, debugging, dart, error-handling

When i am running my flutter application it is showing me the picture stream error can someone solve it i tried every possible solution which i can work on.
Here is the error

```
>  D:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.17.4/lib/src/picture_stream.dart:88:26:
> Error: Type 'DiagnosticableMixin' not found. class PictureStream with
> DiagnosticableMixin {
>                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ /D:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.17.4/lib/src/picture_stream.dart:192:44:
> Error: Type 'DiagnosticableMixin' not found. abstract class
> PictureStreamCompleter with DiagnosticableMixin {
>                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ /D:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.17.4/lib/src/picture_stream.dart:88:7:
> Error: The type 'DiagnosticableMixin' can't be mixed in. class
> PictureStream with DiagnosticableMixin {
>       ^ /D:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.17.4/lib/src/picture_stream.dart:192:16:
> Error: The type 'DiagnosticableMixin' can't be mixed in. abstract
> class PictureStreamCompleter with DiagnosticableMixin


  super.debugFillProperties(properties);
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/D:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.17.4/lib/src/picture_stream.dart:171:30: Error: The method 'toStringShort' isn't defined for the class 'PictureStreamCompleter'.
 - 'PictureStreamCompleter' is from 'package:flutter_svg/src/picture_stream.dart' ('/D:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.17.4/lib/src/picture_stream.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'toStringShort'.
      ifPresent: _completer?.toStringShort(),
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/D:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.17.4/lib/src/picture_stream.dart:266:11: Error: Superclass has no method named 'debugFillProperties'.
    super.debugFillProperties(description);
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'D:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 896

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'D:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 55s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

Comment: What version of flutter are you using? Just upgraded? 

Comment: @EwaoluwaOgunneye yes i recently upgraded my version..

Comment: @EwaoluwaOgunneye my flutter version is 1.20.2

Comment: You should probably just upgrade your flutter_svg then (>=1.80) 

Comment: You're welcome, Moiz 

Answer (score 0):

Hello [Moiz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14011194/moiz-khalil) ‍♂️

I am guessing you use the `flutter_svg` package, or have used it previously.
Whatever the case may be, you have the package in your `pub cache` and it's version has issues with the version of `Flutter` you are currently running.

As suggested by [@BestFastFire](https://github.com/Bestfastfire) in [this Github issue](https://github.com/dnfield/flutter_svg/issues/368), you should be able to fix this by doing one of the following:

---

If your `Flutter` version `< 1.20`, use `flutter_svg: 0.17.4`

If your `Flutter` version `>= 1.20`, use `flutter_svg: 0.18`

---

PS: I had the same issue just now and I solved it by *just **deleting the package** (`flutter_svg`) from the pub cache.* (because, I'm not using `flutter_svg` in my current project)

---

Pub packages, including `flutter_svg` can be found at

`C:\Users\<USERPROFILE>\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org`, if you want to follow this approach.

*Don't forget to replace  with your username*

---

I hope this helps.

If it doesn't, please check the [Github issue](https://github.com/dnfield/flutter_svg/issues/368) for more details.